# Sets containing itself and axiom of regularity

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

I have seen all the available answers to this question here and I am still in doubt. I know that any set x containing a single element, ie itself, can easily shown to be non-existent.

But, how do we go about proving that the following is not possible? -

x = {y, x} - were y is another entity completely disjoint from x. Say, y = 1.

Comment: Note that in those duplicates nobody is assuming that $x=\{x\}$. Just that $x\in x$.

Comment: The axiom of regularity alone does not prove it.  You have to also use the axiom of pairing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_pairing#:~:text=Axiom%20of%20pairing.%20In%20axiomatic%20set%20theory%20and,case%20of%20his%20axiom%20of%20elementary%20sets%20.

Answer (score 0):

If $t\in t$, then $\{t\}\ne \emptyset$ and $t\in \{t\}\cap t$, therefore $\{t\}
$ fails the axiom of regularity. Specialise this argument to the case $t=\{x,y\}$, and you obtain that $x=\{x,y\}$ implies that $\{x\}$ (which is also equal to $\{\{x,y\}\}$) fails regularity.

Comment: So, you are saying that, we repeatedly apply foundation axiom on the elements - in this case? If x = {x,1}, we can argue that {x} fails regularity. Am I correct?

Comment: Why repeatedly? Just once: the one and only element of $\{\{x,y\}\}$ is $\{x,y\}$, and $\{\{x,y\}\}\cap \{x,y\}=\{x\}\cap \{x,y\}$ by hypothesis on $x$. Therefore $\{\{x,y\}\}\cap \{x,y\}\ne \emptyset$, therefore $\{\{x,y\}\}\cap u\ne\emptyset$ for all $v\in \{\{x,y\}\}$.

Comment: Last was supposed to be $u\in\{\{x,y\}\}$, not $v$.